# How to traversal a array in JSON Response in Fiddler CustomRules.js?

Tags: fiddler

In CustomRules.js

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {

        var responseStringOriginal =  oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString();

        var responseJSON = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode(responseStringOriginal);
        var responseJSONObject = responseJSON.JSONObject;
}
```

There is an array in response responseJSONObject , which are like

```
[
    {
        "id": "6661370502453447944"

    },

    { 

        "id": "333" 

    },

    ...

]
```

Question 1: How can I get this array's length or traversal this array?

---

Question 2: How can I save the javascript array to the responseJSON.JSONObject?

I tried

```
var newJSON = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode('{}');
var newJSONObject = newJSON.JSONObject;

newJSONObject['type'] = 'aweme_info'; //ok
newJSONObject['aweme_length'] = 3; //ok
newJSONObject['k']['kell'] = 'good'; //failed

var tpArray = new Array();
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    tpArray.push(i);
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(tpArray); // failed
// how can I convert tpArray to JSON?
```

---

Question 3: Where can I find any documentation about this object "Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON", like what method and properties it have.

---

I tried several ways but nothing works and I can't using the JSON.parse() function in this script.

I also google for the documents of  this object (Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON) and found nothing.

Thank you very much and welcome reply any infomation.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netframework-4.7.2

This script syntax is very similar to DOTNET. You can read the doc above to find the answers.